# Navigate C/C++ Source Code with Emacs

Tags: files, completion, c++, navigation, project

So, i'm finally starting to work with a multi-file Project in C++ and am in need for smart navigation and completion! So far, i've used company-mode (with irony and company-headers), which is great if you're working with single files but if i have defined a class or method in some other file than the one i'm currently editing, i don't get completion or jump to definition and such.

I know about systems like rtags and helm but i feel a bit lost in setting those up!

Can somebody tell me, if i'm even on the right track with these two packages mentioned? If so, can someone guide me in setting such a package up?

Comment: The question is too broad for Stack Exchange, IMO. Maybe try Emacs on Reddit? SE is more for specific (concrete) questions and answers, not for what-are-good-ways-to-use-Emacs. Can you please try to make this question more specific?

Comment: Yes, reddit is a good alternative. Thanks for the comment! I'm rather new to SE as you might expect!

Comment: This is an open question and I don't think it could be answered here (or easily). You have a lot to consider (infrastructure, habits, resources). There's a lot of information available across the internet, so you should also check using your favorite web search service.